# fgetcsv return not exact values

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to read this value `"<! PC:IDJLOGIN; >"` but I get this one `IDJLOGIN` 
whith ths code ,(its the code of the php doc),I have tried with utf-8 and ANSI codification

```
$row = 1;
    if (($handle = fopen($url, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);
            echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
            $row++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
```

Comment: This (most likely) is an issue with how you _visualize_ the data, not with how php reads the data. When trying to visualize data in a browser you need to `htmlescape()` it. You will realize yourself why, once you start thinking about it :-)

Comment: try `<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $data[$c]) . "<br>\n";  ?>`